# Correcting issues with binomial GLM (identified with DHARMa)

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, diagnostic

I'm working with a binomial GLM that I've fit in R using the glm() function.

The percent of deviance explained is decent for my field (35%) and I don't think the residuals vs fitted plot looks too bad.
[image]

But when I plot the simulated residuals using DHARMa, the plots show some clear patterns:
[image]

I've read that patterns in these plots are usually indicative of missing  an important predictor variable, quadratic term, or interaction between variables.

How would I know which one of these is my problem? Do I need to re-fit the GLM trying all possible quadratic terms and all possible interactions? That seems pretty tedious, and also seems like it would increase the chance of identifying one of those terms by chance rather than identifying a true relationship with the response variable.

I don't think I should change the type of model or the distribution/link function - I am fairly certain that binomial and logit are correct for my data. Are there any other options for trying to correct these model diagnostics? Would greatly appreciate any references/textbook suggestions that cover these topics as well.